# How to format a specific part of Flutter code in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I wrote a part of Flutter code in Android Studio and I want to reformat only this part of code (not the entire code). Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the code and press shortcut key `"Alt + Ctrl + L"`.
For whole file `"Alt + Ctrl + Shift + L"`.
Or you can go to Code->Format.

Answer (score 1):

Select that piece of code and use either format shortcut key or menu. That'll only format that piece of code.